# How to use Row_Number() Function in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to generate result set similar in the following table. However, could not achieve the goal. I want to assign each row of the table as shown in the 'I want' column of the following table. 
Following SQL generated 'RowNbr' column. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you

```
SELECT Date, Nbr, status, ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by Date,staus  order by date asc) as RowNbr
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Is Nbr always the same, or are you always filtering to a single Nbr? If not, could you indicate what you want when Nbr is different  (particularly if there are multiple different Nbr values for the same day)?

Comment: Hi Aaron, like you said, I am working on a filtered Nbr to get the result I want. I was hoping to replicate the same logic when it comes to the multiple numbers. Any suggestion?

Comment: Okay, just FYI, partitioning by date doesn't really help you, since that starts the counter over for every new date, which is every new row in this case (I don't think the `RowNbr` in your screen shot was generated by the `ROW_NUMBER()` expression in your code above).

Comment: You are right, if I include both Date and status, I would get 1 in each row. Above chart was generated using partition by status. Thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic "gaps and islands" problem, in case you are searching for similar solutions in the future. Basically you want the counter to reset every time you hit a new status for a given Nbr, ordered by date.

This general overall technique was developed, I believe, by Itzik Ben-Gan, and he has tons of articles and book chapters about it.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT [Date], Nbr, [Status], 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Nbr ORDER BY [Date]) 
       - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Nbr,[Status] ORDER BY [Date])
    FROM dbo.your_table_name
)
SELECT [Date], Nbr, [Status], 
  [I want] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Nbr,rn ORDER BY [Date]) 
FROM cte
ORDER BY Nbr, [Date];
```

On 2012, [you may be able to achieve something similar using `LAG` and `LEAD`](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions); I made a few honest attempts but couldn't get anywhere that would end up being anything less complex than the above.

Comment: Smart! Thats all I was looking for. Thank you